# How to rename and copy a file without renaming the source file?

Tags: python, file, directory, copy, shutil

I am programming something that copies files from a USB drive to a destination folder while also renaming it. Part of my code uses this:

```
    os.rename(src, srcrename) #renames file in USB drive
    shutil.copy2(srcrename, dstname) #copies file to the destination
```

The problem is, I don't want it to rename the files on the USB as it does above. I just want it to rename the files at the destination location.

Comment: Why not use copy2 and change dstname to a custom as you like. Remove os.rename and use a dstNameRename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** Not sure why it didn't work for you but, for copying with metadata, use copy2 instead

```
import os
from shutil import copy2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = "D:\\videoplayback (1).mp4"
    dest = "E:\\vid.mp4"

copy2(src, dest)
```

Do notice the double backlash when using windows paths

**Old anwser**

from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)

If dst is not a directory it will be used as the new name, otherwise it will be copied inside.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but using copyfile will cause me an error. Copyfile also doesn't copy metadata which I would like.

Comment: Check if the new answer solves your problem.

Comment: It works! Personally, I allowed the feature to select the folder path (for the destination)
With that I was able to add the file name at the end of the folder path to save it to the destination with the new name!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: It seems that unlike copy and copy2, copyfile doesn't have certain permissions in some cases. That's why I was having that error.